# JQuery Append to a child element

Tags: html, jquery, dom-manipulation, jquery-append

I have a jQuery like this.

```
$.each($(".fc-daygrid-day "), function (key, val) {
  var dateYMD = $(this).attr("data-date");
  console.log(this); 
  $(this).append(`<div class="fc-dailytotal" id='dailytotal-" + dateYMD + "'></div>`);
});
```

Which returns something like this. ( this is what I get when I `console.log(this)` )

```
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future fc-day-other" data-date="2020-11-05">
  <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"> <!-- line 2 -->
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">5</a></div>
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"></div>
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-dailytotal" id="dailytotal-&quot; + dateYMD + &quot;">0</div> <!-- line 1 -->
</td>
```

I want to append the line 1 inside the line 2 div tag ? final result i want is as following. Thank you. (i am new to JQuery)

```
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future fc-day-other" data-date="2020-11-05">
  <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"> <!-- line 2 -->
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">5</a></div>
    <div class="fc-dailytotal" id="dailytotal-&quot; + dateYMD + &quot;">0</div> <!-- line 1 -->
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"></div>
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find()` to target the child element and then `after()` to insert the content to be displayed directly below it. Also note that your string concatenation syntax is incorrect. As you're using a template literal you need to use `${foo}` to insert the value in to the string. Try this:

```
$.each($(".fc-daygrid-day"), function (key, val) {
  var dateYMD = $(this).attr("data-date");
  $(this).find('.fc-daygrid-day-top').after(`<div class="fc-dailytotal" id='dailytotal-${dateYMD}'></div>`);
});
```

In addition it's worth noting that the code can be improved. Firstly use `data()` to read a `data` attribute so that the result is more strongly typed. Also, given what you're actually attempting to achieve you don't need an explicit `each()` loop at all. You can provide a function to `after()` which generates the content dynamically.

```js
$('.fc-daygrid-day .fc-daygrid-day-top').after(function() {
  let dateYMD = $(this).closest('.fc-daygrid-day').data('date');
  return `<div class="fc-dailytotal" id="dailytotal-${dateYMD}">Example: ${dateYMD}</div>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future fc-day-other" data-date="2020-11-05">
        <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
          <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">5</a></div>
          <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"></div>
          <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future fc-day-other" data-date="2021-12-15">
        <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
          <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">10</a></div>
          <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"></div>
          <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. this sloved my problem. thank you. also can i use `find('.fc-daygrid-day-top.fc-daygrid-day-top')` somthing like this to access `fc-daygrid-day-top` div ?

Comment: You can use any valid CSS selector to find the element. The one in your comment wouldn't work though, as you've repeated the same class twice.

Comment: ohh my bad there..thank you very much i slove my issue and learn few more things about jquery. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `append`, you just need to use `prepend`:

```
$.each($(".fc-daygrid-day"), function (key, val) {
  var dateYMD = $(this).attr("data-date");
  $(this).prepend(`<div class="fc-dailytotal" id='dailytotal-" + dateYMD + "'>prepending</div>`);
});
```

`prepend` will insert the new node *before the first child* of the element you are adding to, whereas `append` inserts it *after the last child*. Ref: [MDN Docs for prepend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

**Working Example:**

```js
$.each($(".fc-daygrid-day"), function (key, val) {
  var dateYMD = $(this).attr("data-date");
  $(this).prepend(`<div class="fc-dailytotal" id='dailytotal-" + dateYMD + "'>ADDED</div>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future fc-day-other" data-date="2020-11-05">
  <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"> <!-- line 2 -->
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">5</a></div>
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"></div>
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```